# Schdule SP via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to schedule a stored procedure to run once at a specific datetime in SQL Server 2014 Express via a ASP.NET/C# web page. The SP needs parameters.
I have the service SQL Server Agent.

Which is the simplest way to proceed?

Comment: What is the relevance of an ASP.NET/C# web page? If you are just running a stored procedure why can't you [schedule a job using SQL Server Agent?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

Comment: What parameters does the stored procedure need? How are they supplied? Is this where the webpage comes into it, i.e. to supply the parameters? I think some more details are required to provide a complete answer.

Comment: Please tell us why web page is important. If you want to run your SP on schedule - use Agent. If you want to pass parameters from web page, then store these parameters in a table when user submits a page. Then let SP read parameters from table on execution.

Comment: FYI for all the other comments: Agent is not available in EXPRESS edition, you'd have to use something else such as the windows scheduler.